# XSLT: Omit last newline in output

Tags: xml, bash, xslt

I am have the following xml file:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">value1</td>
    <td align="left">not wanted 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="left">value2</td>
    <td align="left">not wanted 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to print all `value x` each on a seperate row. The following XSL does almost what I want:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes">
  </xsl:output>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/table/tr">
    <xsl:value-of select="./td[1]" />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
$ xsltproc filter.xsl file.xml
value1
value2

$
```

As you can see, it prints a trailing newline after the last value. I do not want this newline. I could easily delete it by piping the result to `sed`, but that seems like a rather clumsy solution.

Can the last newline be omitted with XSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I.** Just look ahead, if there is any following sibling `tr`:

```
<xsl:template match="/table/tr">
    <xsl:value-of select="./td[1]" />
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::tr">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**II.** **Other** suitable solution would be, to go via templates and `position()`:

```
<xsl:template match="/table/tr">
    <xsl:value-of select="./td[1]" />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/table/tr[last()]" priority="1.1">
    <xsl:value-of select="./td[1]" />
</xsl:template>
```

[last()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-last) Get last position of a context node.

`priority` is needed to avoid any ambiguous rule warnings.

---

EDIT / Advice 1: self-close your `xsl:output`.

Answer (score 0):

Add an exception for the last `tr`:

```
<xsl:template match="/table/tr[position()=last()]">
  <xsl:value-of select="./td[1]" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an XSLT 2.0 processor:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="/table/tr/td[1]" separator="&#xa;"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or an XQuery 1.0 processor:

```
string-join(/table/tr/td[1], '&#xa;')
```